# How to run a docker container that's connected to nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

So I have a DigitalOcean server and a valid domain name and I want to get HTTPS support for my backend. I want to use Let's Encrypt and the common way to use this from what I've seen is in conjunction with Nginx. I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to run it though. If I run my docker container than port 80 is already in use so that means the nginx service cannot be started, but if I start the nginx, I can't curl my backend.

This is my Dockerfile for my backend

```yaml
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8

LABEL maintainer="Sebastian Ramirez <tiangolo@gmail.com>"

WORKDIR /app/backend

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
COPY . .
CMD ["uvicorn", "backend.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

This is my nginx config

```
server{
        listen 80;
       server_name example.xyz www.example.xyz;
       location / {
           include proxy_params;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
       }
}
```

I can curl to example.com and get a 200 and localhost:80

EDIT:
I can not curl to my domain name now but I can curl to localhost:8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options, but it's probably easiest to first set up uvicorn to run on another port (such as `8080`)

Then use [`-p` to map ("publish")](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) the container's web port to one on the host's (you can set the mapping between any port(s), but making it the same can simplify future understanding)

```sh
docker run ... -p 8080:8080
```

Then in your nginx configuration, set it up to proxy_pass to your mapped port

```
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

Restart nginx after you do this to pick up the new config

Comment: I'm getting 500 internal server error, I'll post my latest dockerfile and nginx conf

Comment: I can curl to localhost:8000 but not my domain name now and I'm running `docker run -dp 8000:8000`

Comment: Okay nvm it turns out I needed to restart nginx for my changes to be up ty!

Comment: Excellent - I added a little more including that restarting nginx was necessary!